# Changing mouse scroll action in emacs/iTerm2

Tags: macos, emacs, iterm2

When I scroll with my mouse in emacs in iTerm2, it recently started moving the cursor in the emacs terminal, rather than it used to just scroll up and down the iTerm buffer.

I inadvertently clicked yes when iTerm2 prompted be on the top if I wanted to change something. I don't know what that "something" said, as I just meant to close out and accidentally changed something.

I really hate this new behavior and wanted to change back. I can't seem to find how to solve the problem as I'm not exactly sure what I changed. Googling a general solution for scrolling in iTerm2 or emacs in terminal came up with nothing useful or nothing that actually works.